# Center div to bottom, fitting width to inner text

Tags: css

Here's what I've tried,the problem is that it only center my div when I set a fixed width in px.
How can I make the width to fit to the inner text?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="enclose">
    <div id="problem">
    MY TEXT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#problem {
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:200px;
}
#enclose {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7bqsdt6o/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text-align: center` on your parent div i.e. `<div id="enclose">`, this would center your `<div id="problem">`.

```css
#enclose {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="enclose">
    <div id="problem">
    MY TEXT HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've used `display:inline`; and `width:auto;`, and I guess it worked. Thanks.http://jsfiddle.net/7bqsdt6o/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-align: center` on parent element (`#enclose`) or the CSS3 feature `width: intrinsic;`.

Working code (at least on Chrome 38) - [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/madcorp/pen/vchtl)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I would need support to IE, http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width